# Storing a value from a function in JS

Tags: javascript, function, storing-data

So, I'm having trouble keeping a value from a function.

```
var A4 = 0;
var A1 = 1;
var A2 = 2;
var A3 = 3;
var ROW1 = [A1, A2, A3, A4];
function contains(a, obj) { 
    var i = a.length;
    while (i--) {
       if (a[i] === obj) {
           return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The accepted value of this function when used with the given variables is 4.

```
var InRow = function(cell, row) {
    cell = 1;
    if (contains(row, cell)) {
        cell = 2;
        if (contains(row, cell)) {
            cell = 3;
            if (contains(row, cell)) {
                cell = 4;
                if (contains(row, cell)) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    cell = 4;
                }
            } else {
                cell = 3;
            }
        } else {
            cell = 2;
        }
} else {
    cell = 1;
    }
    console.log(cell)
```

That console.log gives the accepted value, four.

```
};
InRow(A4, ROW1);
console.log(A4);
```

However, this one gives a value of 0, no matter what.

I am wondering if there is any way to store the value from the second function to use later? i.e., make the second console.log return 4.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have pass-by-reference/pointer arguments. `cell` is a value copy of `A4` and changing a copy won't affect the original.

Comment: To do what you want to do, you would have to assign cell to A4. `A4=cell`. But that's not very efficient so just use Barış Uşaklı's code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you just return the value? Or am I missing something?

```
var InRow = function(cell, row) {
    cell = 1;
    if (contains(row, cell)) {
        cell = 2;
        if (contains(row, cell)) {
            cell = 3;
            if (contains(row, cell)) {
                cell = 4;
                if (contains(row, cell)) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    cell = 4;
                }
            } else {
                cell = 3;
            }
        } else {
            cell = 2;
        }
    } else {
        cell = 1;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

And then :

```
var cell = InRow(A4, ROW1);
console.log(cell);
```

Also what is the point of passing in `A4` into the function and then overwriting it with a value of 1? You can rewrite the whole thing to this and it will have the same effect.

```
var InRow = function(row) {
    var cell = 1;
    if (contains(row, cell)) {
        cell = 2;
        if (contains(row, cell)) {
            cell = 3;
            if (contains(row, cell)) {
                cell = 4;
                if (contains(row, cell)) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    cell = 4;
                }
            } else {
                cell = 3;
            }
        } else {
            cell = 2;
        }
    } else {
        cell = 1;
    }
    return cell;
}

var cell = InRow(ROW1);
console.log(cell);
```

Comment: Ugh.. I feel so stupid.

BTW, overwriting it is the only way to check the value. It checks 1, then 2, hen 3, then 4.

Comment: Check my edit, no point passing in A4 into the function if it's not going to be used.